# Save Interactive Python (using script)

Tags: python, linux, macos

I would like to save the input and the output of a Python session when providing the input as a file.

In interactive mode, I would type a command of expressions and get their evaluation, as shown:

```
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar  8 2016, 18:01:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> abs(3)
3
>>> abs(-3)
3
```

The text above is my desired output.

When I write these two expressions in `p.py`:

```
abs(3)
abs(-3)
```

and execute  `python p.py`, I don't get any output, which is fine because Python runs in non-iteractive mode. If I execute `python -i < p.py`, I just get the output, not the input.

So, I dediced to use the `script` command.

However, with `script`, I get different results in MacOs and Linux (and none of them save what I would like).

If I execute `script -q output.txt python -i <p.py` on MacOs, file `output.txt`contains

```
abs(-3)
abs(3)
Python 2.7.11 (default, Mar  8 2016, 18:01:39)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> abs(-3)
3
>>> abs(3)
3
```

which is the desired output but with the input of `p.py` preppended to it.

If I execute `script -q output.txt -c "python -i <p.py"` on Linux, file `output.txt` contains

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Jun 22 2015, 19:33:41)
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 3
>>> 3
```

which is far from I would like.

In brief:

- How could I save a file that reproduces the interactive Python session when redirecting input to it?

Additionally,

- Why do the MacOs and Linux implementations of `script` work so differently?